# Unable to import 'request' module in Flask - "type object 'Flask' has no attribute 'request'"

Tags: python, flask

after installing the requests module into my virtual environment, my flask application can no longer import/access the request module.

i am able to import requests successfully, but not request:

[image]

As we can see, 'request' is greyed out and unable to be accessed as it previously was in my application.

When I hover over the greyed 'request' it says '"request" is not accessed, Pylance'

This is the output of `pip list` in my virtual environment

[image]

Comment: _"request" is not accessed,_ means that is never used in you code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import webbrowser
from requests import request
from flask import request
url = 'https://some_page.html'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
request.
```

On these moment you can use request.

Without any line with command request, you have information with "the greyed 'request' it says '"request" is not accessed, Pylance."

Comment: why would you import `request` from `requests` and immediately override it with `request` from `flask`? In the OP case PyLance just informs them that they not use `flask.request` in their code.

Comment: Also, both `requests.request` and `flask.request` are never used in your code, so they will be grayed out too as unused imports - the same like in OP case.

Comment: On this case you can use only request command, when I use import I must use all times requests.request. Maybe I'm wrong, but sometimes is easier for me

Comment: You don't understand, do you? Both imports are never used. So your code will work without them, why do you import them? Ignore the fact that your example is irrelevant to OP question. And because you first import `request` from `requests` package and immediately, on the next line you import `request` from `flask` if it happens to use name `request` in your code (which you don't) name `request` will be the one from `flask` package.

Comment: As others pointed out, these are unused import statements. Thats problem 1, but more importantly, if you actually want to use "from requests import request", you couldnt, because you're importing "from flask import request" under the same name. To avoid this, you can "from flask import request as flask_request" and use this under the name "flask_request". Now you can use both flask request and python request at the same time and avoid confusion of the two.